# Can't load an obj file with three.js and ObjLoader2

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, objloader

I imported from cdn ObjLoader2(). I'm trying to load an obj file but on the console I get two errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'myfilepath.obj' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

and...

```
three.module.js:35911 GET myfilepath.obj net::ERR_FAILED
load    @   three.module.js:35911
load    @   OBJLoader2.js:301
(anonymous) @   index.html:31
```

Here's my code:

```
  <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module">
      import { OBJLoader2 } from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r115/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js";
      import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
      const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvasObj");
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
      const fov = 45;
      const aspect = 2;
      const near = 0.1;
      const far = 5;
      const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
      camera.position.set(0, 5, 2);
      const scena = new THREE.Scene();
      const objLoader = new OBJLoader2();
      objLoader.load("Iphone8.obj", (root) => {
        scena.add(root);
        render();
      });
        renderer.render(scena, camera);
    </script>
```

I think it's a problem with library importing, but I don't understand the error. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you're running things locally, and due to browsers' same origin policy security restrictions, loading from a file system will fail with a security exception.

You need to run your code on a local web server in order to load 3D models.

You can follow how to on three.js's official website and documentation.

[How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally)

[Loading 3D Models](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models)

Hope this helps! Best of Luck!

Comment: Yes after 30 minutes of fire :,) I started a visual studio live server and it worked ,thanks anyway ! :)